# Where to put model-specific delete code in ASP.Net Core 2 with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

i was wondering about the following for some time now:

I got a pretty complex Data Model designed with EF Core. 
Let's say I got an entity class A with some 1-to-1, 1-to-many and many-to-many references to other classes, which in turn have further relationships etc.

Let's say my class A has an 1-to-many relationship with B, with has in turn another 1-to-many relation to C.
Now I need to delete an object of class A. That delete must delete all referenced B-objects, which in turn have to delete all referenced C-objects.

In older projects with lazy-loading I didn't have much of a problem with that. If one references wasn't loaded yet, EF would load it and delete what needs to be deleted. So I just put my delete-specific method right in class A.
(it looks like 'foreach(var b in this.Bs) mapper.delete(b)'

Now without lazy-loading, i was wondering what the best approach is:
if the relationships aren't loaded, i will either get a nullpointer exception or a violation for foreign key constraints, as the referenced objects aren't deleted.

So should I put the reference loading right into the model class in that delete-Method? Should I load those references before like in the controller or a business layer and then call the delete? Or should the whole delete thing be handled differently.

PS: i know the database could just do some cascade stuff, but let's say, i need to log each deletion of my objects or have to do other in-code stuff.

Comment: I'd say the "where" part of the question is rather opinion/solution-specific than something that could be generally answered. Pick the one which fits the best into how your code is organized. On the "how" part, I'd personally separate it into two stages: a preparation and an execution stage. In the preparation one, I'd collect the Ids of the entities to be deleted, and in the execution stage, I'd actually mark them for deletion and commit afterwards. The reason is that if you traverse the results along the nav properties then you will run into some nasty select n+1 problems....

Comment: ... but, if you collect the ids on a per table basis, you essentially do as many queries as many different tables participating in the deletion are, plus one command for actually deleting them. This is way more work but yields significant performance benefits.

Comment: Why? If you have configured your properties correctly, the cascading delete should be in place (check your snapshot/migration files). When you delete the parent/master entity all entities which depend on it and their dependencies will be deleted to. Did you even tried that, before trying to do all the delete "logic" yourself?! A major point of an ORM (and relational DBs cascading setting) is to take care of this

Comment: May be helpful too: [EF Core Docs: Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). But I suspect your entities are not configured correctly, so the FK relationships aren't set to cascade delete. see last two paragraphs on the linked docs. Other than that, you'll need to do a [eager load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) to load all entities and its child objects before performing the operation

Comment: @Tseng Yes I know about the cascade behaviour, but I haven't found a way there to do some delete-specific operations, for example log something or even notify some user / admin of a deletion. I totally agree that some cascading deletion should be handled by the framework. Thanks for the advice

Comment: And the issue with eager loading is which one? Lazy loading shouldnt be done anyways with web apps

Comment: That was the question. Should I put the eager- / explicit loading part right in my "prepareDelete" method or rather in a service layer? The problem I see in the service layer is just: if there are serveral cascading deletes, like A -> B -> C, and on some future point I need to add a C -> D reference that needs to be deleted too on cascade, then I need to update that service layer that was actually just concerned with deleting A.

Comment: With lazy loading, I didn't need that consideration, as C would have loaded D on its own.
Btw. why is lazy-loading in web apps a bad idea? Can you explain?